# Scala | How to get the object reference for comparison?

Tags: scala

How to get an object reference in Scala? I would like to compare those references to see if it's a new or old object which is being used.

```
var objArr: ArrayBuffer[someObj] = new ArrayBuffer[someObj](0)
// fill array
objArr(0) // how to get the internal reference of that array object and not the content of it?
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Why exactly do you want to get the reference? If you do not use a case class and you do not override `equals` then you can just use normal equality to compare by reference.

Comment: Yep, that was the operator I was missing on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `objArr(0)` seems to be what you want

```
class MyClass
val x = new MyClass
var objArr: ArrayBuffer[MyClass] = ArrayBuffer(x)
objArr(0) eq x // true
objArr(0) eq new MyClass // false
```